# How to calculate elapsed time until now in Elasticsearch script?

Tags: elasticsearch

In an Elasticsearch query I want to calculate the average time elapsed from the time a document updated until now. How can I do this using painless script?

I am doing this but it does not work:

```
        "avg_wait":{
          "avg":{
            "script": {
              "params": {
                "rightNow": "{{new DateTime()}}"
              }, 
              "source": "(params['rightNow']- doc['lastUpdated'].value )/ 1000*60*60*24",
              "lang": "painless"
            }
          }
```